# How to display multiple notifications at once in system tray

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

We have a requirement to create an app that would listen to certain events and would display notifications/popups in system tray.

I am looking a way to display my notifications just like skype do, it creates a stack of notifications in case of multiple events, second option would be like outlook displays email popups, but i want something solid, windows baloon tips does not seem to provide much control and pretty much OS dependent.

Is there a  way to accomplish it using win API or a .net library ? just give me pointers.

Comment: c# gurus, please guide me...

Answer (score -1):

This is the a simple way I solved it

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     private NotifyIcon trayIcon;
     private ContextMenu traymenu;

     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        traymenu = new ContextMenu();
        traymenu.MenuItems.Add("Exit", OnExit);

        trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        trayIcon.Text = "Cpu usage: " + "something from program" + "%";
        trayIcon.Icon = new Icon(SystemIcons.Application, 40, 40);

        trayIcon.ContextMenu = trayMenu;
        trayIcon.Visible = true;
}
```

Now the message will show when you hover/click on the trayIcon, but I guess you can show message when something happens in the program by calling: trayIcon.contextMenu.show();

Comment: i am looking for something more than balloon tips.